# Anyone replicated a sql server db into AWS using NATIVE replication NOT AWS DMS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, dms

Just a yes / no hopefully.

Can you replicate into a sql server rds multi az aws instance from an on premise sql server (standard edition 2008r2)

I know there is aws dms and im not asking about that.

There is aws directory services which i believe allows you to see an aws rds db as if its on your network and this may solve some of the issue as you need to be on the same domain or something for native replication.

This [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html) says RDS doesnt support replication but is that only when its the master and not when its an read only replica destination. Its not really clear.

Answer (score 1):

The answer currently is no, I believe.

I have looked at using linked servers, but that currently does not work for this situation either. From the below link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Every person/resource I have spoken to in AWS point me to DMS, which as your describe in your question is not what you are looking for.

The only other place I came across in my travels and dugout of my bookmarks was this company https://www.attunity.com/products/cloudbeam/attunity-replicate-amazon-rds-databases-amazon-ec2/ and this product. But I have not tried it so I cannot speak if it is any good or not for what you want. But may help you.

Comment: Thanks James. We are looking into AWS DMS but are getting people saying that the total logical row size can only be 8000 bytes including any "max" fields e.g varchar(max) and that going over that can lead to unexpected results - sometimes it will work, sometimes not. I dont belive it personally. Basically if you want to ensure it works then all tables must not be oversized and remove any blob/clob fields which i think cant be true as its too restrictive other than for trivial or specialized dbs. We are doing testing currently on AWS DMS to test what does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Also we have noticed that the DMS fails to delete records for the tables with composite primary key. It works for table with single primary key coumns